# I've just bought PAW and registered with their site. How do I use PawPrints?

Tags: paw-app

I've just bought [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) and, while exploring the app found a mention of `pawprints`, which appear to be some sort of saved snippets or requests or something.  I registered with the website and it tells me I have no saved pawprints. I've searched all over the help files and documentation and can't actually see how to create a pawprint, or even a clear definition of what a pawprint actually is.

So my questions are, what are `pawprints` and how do I use them?

Comment: Yep, I agree we should be more clear about Pawprints :) Here's a blog article about them: http://blog.luckymarmot.com/posts/pawprint/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thanks Micha,

From [the Blog Post](http://blog.luckymarmot.com/posts/pawprint/) (which Google couldn't find when I searched)

> Last May, we launched Pawprint, a quick way to share the requests you tested in Paw. The idea of a getting a short link that you can paste anywhere, sharing what you just see on screen, was very appealing and something we wanted to do almost since the beginning of Paw.
>
> That's handy to report bugs to the API provider (often those backend guys sitting on the other side of the room), or to show to the consumers (often the client folks playing with smartphones and web browsers) how your PATCH endpoint works.
>
> In Paw, just hit `⌘/,` and a permalink will be copied. Paste it anywhere from Slack and GitHub tickets, to StackOverflow answers.
>
> You'll also get client code generated in many languages, plus cURL or HTTPie command lines, to run the same request from code.

Apparently the Paw website is being updated now to make this clearer.